SLF3S-4000B not recognised by Arduino Uno R3
I have a Sensirion SLF3S-4000B connected to SDA/SCL lines of the Arduino uno through a logic level shifter (connected like in this example: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/retired---using-the-logic-level-converter) with SDA/SCL sensor to IC connections connected to bi-direction TXO/I lines of LLC, everything seems to be connected correctly but when I run the example code below, the Arduino does not seem to recognise the sensor (No I2C device found). I am unsure of why the sensor is not being recognised when I am correctly pulling up to 5V at the Arduino with the level shifter. I am supplying the Arduino with 7V via Vin.  
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial); // Wait for the serial port to initialize if it's not ready yet.
  
  Serial.println("\nI2C Scanner");
}

void loop() {
  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;

  Serial.println("Scanning...");

  nDevices = 0;
  for (address = 1; address < 127; address++ ) {
    // The i2c_scanner uses the return value of
    // the Write.endTransmisstion to see if
    // a device did acknowledge to the address.
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    error = Wire.endTransmission();

    if (error == 0) {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address < 16) 
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print(address, HEX);
      Serial.println("  !");
      
      nDevices++;
    }
    else if (error == 4) {
      Serial.print("Unknown error at address 0x");
      if (address < 16)
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.println(address, HEX);
    }    
  }
  if (nDevices == 0)
    Serial.println("No I2C devices found\n");
  else
    Serial.println("done\n");
  
  delay(5000); // Wait 5 seconds for the next scan
}


Is the Sensirion sensor actually SLF3S-4000B, since SLFS-4000B doesn't seem to be a valid part number? Also, to help get an answer can you edit the question to show a schematic of how the sensor, level shifter, Arduino uno and power supplies are connected.

Hi Chester, I have updated for your reference thanks. I accidentally wrote 5.5V in the schematic but I mean 5V

From looking at the datasheets the Arduino uno operates at 5 V and the SLF3S-4000B sensor at 3.3 V. Therefore, shouldn't the Arduino uno be connected to the "high voltage" (HV) side of the level translator and the SLF3S-4000B sensor to the "low voltage" (LV) side of the level translator. Whereas the schematic appears to show the Arduino uno connected to the "low voltage" side and the SLF3S-4000B sensor connected to the "high voltage" side. Have I misunderstood the schematic, or is that the cause of the problem?

If you are meticulously following sparkfun tutorial and not getting desired result, maybe it's a bad SLF3S-4000B.
